# SQL - How can I insert data "only" to the new column I added to an existing table (multiple rows)?

Tags: sql

I added a new column to an existing table called "age", I tried to insert multiple ages to different rows only to this new column but have been receiving errors. Can someone tell me what is the syntax and if there is a better way of doing it? Much appreciated!

P.S. I do want to keep the existing data as it, and I'm only looking to insert data which is the ages to the multiple people already stored in the database.

Comment: In SQL, `INSERT` refers to a *row*, which is not what you're looking to do. You're looking for [UPDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).

Comment: Should be no problem.  Show (add to your question by using [edit]) your code.

Comment: Hover over the sql-tag underneath your question... you will see that it is asking you to add a tag for the specific RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the INSERT INTO because you will add a new row,  instead use the UPDATE statement to update the data already stored.

UPDATE table_name
SET age=value
WHERE id=somevalue;